# Why Isn't the Dock Showing/Hiding Correctly

Tags: display, mojave, dock

I use two external displays and a MacBook Pro. I'm running Mojave 10.14.6. I've noticed a problem with the Dock. Expected behavior is the dock appears when I bring the mouse to the bottom of either the external displays or the laptop screen. This doesn't work. The dock stays where it was located.

This is where it gets weird.

If I want the dock to move, I have to select a window in the display that I want the dock on, then type text into a text field in that window, then bring the mouse to the bottom of the screen. That makes the dock move.
Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: What text in what field?

Comment: Any text in any field. I.e. when I try to get the dock to show at the bottom of my external monitor by bringing the mouse cursor to the bottom of the screen it doesn't work, but if I enter any text into this comment box (assume that this browser window is open on that external display), then when I bring the mouse cursor to the bottom of the screen the dock appears.

Answer (score 1):

I am using 10.14.6 also, and have noticed no issues with the dock on my computer, except I just use Auto-Hide for the dock so it disappears until I need it. Whenever I move the mouse to either screen the dock pops up -- but this might because there is still only one visible instance of the dock.

But I noticed something similar to what you describe on a coworker's 27" iMac the other day.

On the second monitor was the Mail app and Finder was the active app on the primary screen. The dock was on the screen with the Mail app. Moving the Mail app to the primary screen the dock moved.

I don't know what the rules are for the dock, but if it gets stuck try toggling on/off hiding. (Right-click on the separator between standard an recent apps, then select "Turn Hiding On/Off").

[image]